# Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Anime & Manga Stack Exchange](http://anime.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is the significance of anime characters' catch phrases?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/what-is-the-significance-of-anime-characters-catch-phrases)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What is the "foreign" language that is used in Suisei no Gargantia?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/what-is-the-foreign-language-that-is-used-in-suisei-no-gargantia)

  **Net Score: 19** (Excellent: 19, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why does Tsubasa Reservoir Chronicle use the same characters as Card Captor Sakura?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/why-does-tsubasa-reservoir-chronicle-use-the-same-characters-as-card-captor-saku)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What are the types of jutsus that exist in Naruto?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/what-are-the-types-of-jutsus-that-exist-in-naruto)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [What is the origin of the face fault?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/what-is-the-origin-of-the-face-fault)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [How can the man in the back see?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/how-can-the-man-in-the-back-see)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Why does cutting out part of Orochimaru’s soul cause him to lose the use of his arms?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3296/why-does-cutting-out-part-of-orochimarus-soul-cause-him-to-lose-the-use-of-his)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Was anything past volume 7 ever released in English?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/satisfaction-guaranteed-was-anything-past-volume-7-ever-released-in-english)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What did the old man say to the bartender at the end?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/what-did-the-old-man-say-to-the-bartender-at-the-end)

  **Net Score: 14** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why did Kabuto heal Hinata?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3244/why-did-kabuto-heal-hinata)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 0)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my thoughts on the questions.

[**What is the “foreign” language that is used in Suisei no Gargantia?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3418/24) - Excellent

This question only has one answer, but it is well-written. The page shows up near the top of a search for "Suisei no Gargantia language" which was already a common enough search term for Google to autocomplete to it. The pages above it don't have anywhere near the same level of detail. The answer is also not just copied from an external source, though it includes several external sources for further verification.

[**Why did Kabuto heal Hinata?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3244/24) - Satisfactory

This seems to be a common question, as I found multiple other sites with essentially the same question. We don't come up particularly high on a search for the question title, though we're still on the first page and the question has a good number of hits. The answer here is higher quality than the other sites in my opinion, but it still comes down to speculation to some degree. This sort of question could probably get multiple answers with different perspectives, but it only has one. All together, this could definitely be improved on, but it doesn't have any serious problems.

[**Why does Tsubasa Reservoir Chronicle use the same characters as Card Captor Sakura?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2988/24) - Satisfactory

The answers on this question are correct and well-written, but the question is almost entirely unsearchable as-is. Because of this, I almost marked the question as 'Needs Improvement'. The title is too specific and won't bring in any search traffic. The question didn't come up in any of the searches I performed. Longer titles need to match search criteria more closely to come up highly in results, and this isn't matching anyone's searches. A better title would be something to the effect of "What is the connection between Tsubasa Reservoir Chronicle and Card Captor Sakura?" though it would likely require rewording the existing question and answers slightly.

[**How can the man in the back see?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3328/24) - Satisfactory

This question has a lot of room for improvement. It's not going to bring in any search traffic as it is right now. The answer isn't really an answer either; it's just a note that the same character appears elsewhere. A complete answer would be an improvement. Despite these issues, I still rated the question as satisfactory, simply because I don't see any way to improve it as it is right now. The title isn't going to be searchable unless we can find the character's name. As for the answer, this is quite possibly a case where no satisfactory answer exists. Rating this as "Needs Work" would entail that I have suggestions for how to improve it, which I do not.

[**What is the origin of the face fault?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3130/24) - Needs Improvement

This is a good question, and we come up highly in the search results, and has a lot of traffic, but there's only one answer, which I don't consider satisfactory. It's essentially just a quote of a single other source, and one which comes before us in a search for "face fault origin" at that. Unfortunately, despite a bounty, this question failed to attract any higher quality answers, but it could desperately use some. As a note, this trope is not exclusive to anime, though it is particularly common in anime, so it's a bit questionable whether it really belongs on this site in my opinion.

[**What are the types of jutsus that exist in Naruto?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3040/24) - Satisfactory

This is a list question, and the list is rather long, but I think it's okay. We're nowhere near the top of a search for "Naruto types of jutsu" which was a Google autocomplete result. The content here is good, and of interest to a lot of people, but the question only has 75 views. The top answer starting with a disclaimer isn't really great either. However, the content here is pretty good; it's just already been listed elsewhere on higher traffic sites which are more natural places for it. With that in mind, I don't know how we could improve these, apart from deleting the disclaimer note.

[**What is the significance of anime characters' catch phrases?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3317/24) - Satisfactory

The answer here is high quality. Unfortunately, we aren't getting any traffic from the question. "Anime catchphrases" as a search already has lots of other high-quality sites, and we aren't anywhere near the top. I don't see us getting to the top of that search, at least not unless someone feels like writing a far-more in depth answer. That probably isn't worth it.

[**Why does cutting out part of Orochimaru’s soul cause him to lose the use of his arms?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3296/24) - Satisfactory

This doesn't seem to get much traffic either, and it's hard to search for. A better title might help that. It would also help a lot for a question like this to have images, at least in the answers, so that it's clear to someone like me (who doesn't know much about Naruto) what people are talking about. In my opinion, trying to get this question to bring in lots of traffic is futile, and the answers are good enough as is right now, though there is certainly room for improvement.

[**What did the old man say to the bartender at the end?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3334/24) - Excellent

Despite a bit of a questionable title, we're at the top of a search for "Death Billiards ending". The question has only 128 views, but Death Billiards is a single 25-minute movie, so it's not going to be a huge traffic magnet no matter what. The answer is thorough, though there's still a bit more room for other people to add their own speculation.

[**'Satisfaction Guaranteed' - was anything past volume 7 ever released in English?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3306/24) - Satisfactory (I accidentally clicked Excellent in review queue)

We come up highly in searches for both "Satisfaction Guaranteed English" (1st relevant result) and "Satisfaction Guaranteed English release" (1st result overall). The answer is also complete and well-written. The only problem is that Satisfaction Guaranteed is a rather niche series. The question only has 42 hits. I have no doubt that people who want to find this information are finding it through us, but there just aren't many people in that category in the first place.

---

Overall thoughts:

- We could use more answers per question in almost all cases.
- Titles matter a lot in terms of SEO. A few of the above posts could immediately be improved in terms of traffic if all we changed was the title.
- Despite being very popular, Naruto questions tended to have average levels of traffic or lower. I suspect this is precisely because it's so popular. Most of the natural questions have already been asked and answered elsewhere, and we just aren't likely to beat those sites anytime soon in terms of search results.
- The post on Death Billiards was the 4th highest trafficked of all of the review queue posts, despite being about a fairly niche series. This indicates to me that we can get a lot of traffic through even fairly niche anime if we have high quality content. However, the Satisfaction Guaranteed post, despite also being pretty high quality, didn't generate nearly as many hits, so we need to be posting the same things that people are asking about with regards to these sorts of series.
- In some cases, even when a post has obvious issues (e.g. hard to search for), there is no obvious way to fix them. Unfortunately, the best thing to do in these situations is probably just to ignore them and focus on improving the posts which can be improved easily.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have one answer for each review page rather than having everyone to create their own answer explaining every single vote they made?

Comment: @atlantiza You're welcome to answer however you want. I didn't see much point in posting 4 or 5 answers for different questions, so I just decided to explain all of my votes in one answer.

Comment: It's more organized and easier to see the problems with each question. I want to comment about a few of them but I'm not going to make a whole answer for my few suggestions.

Comment: @atlantiza if you have suggestions, you **should** make an answer. There's nothing wrong with a short answer with some suggestions.